# Can you hide empty terms using get_term_children?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to `get_term_children` of a specific term:

```
$style_categories = get_term_children( 29, 'product_cat' ); 

if ( $style_categories ) :

    foreach ( $style_categories as $style ) :

        $child = get_term_by( 'id', $style, 'product_cat' );

        echo '<h3>' . $child->name . '</h3>';

              // post query goes here

    endforeach;

endif;
```

This works, but it shows terms when they're empty, and there doesn't appear to be a `hide_empty` option for get_term_children.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `get_term_children()` function there is nothing to pass which will hide empty terms. You could do that in your foreach as each term has a property which holds how many posts it is assigned:

```
foreach( $style_categories as $style ) {
    
    $child = get_term_by( 'id', $style, 'product_cat' );
    
    // Skip empty terms
    if( $child->count <= 0 ) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

The way it stands now you're creating multiple queries - a better solution would be to use [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) instead.

```
get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'child_of' => 29] );
```

`get_terms` will hide the terms that have no post, you can change that with the `hide_empty` argument.

Comment: @LBF - Can this type of functionality not be achieved with `get_terms()`? I've updated my answer but it's probably inefficient.

Comment: Oh right -- I guess I could just use child_of with get_terms to do the same thing? D'oh.

Comment: @LBF - if that works for you post it as an answer - I'm not sure the core differences between the two functions but as it stands now you're making a ton of extra queries.

Comment: It did work, thank you. But you're right. I'll use get_terms instead. Not sure how I got so twisted around. Still learning...

Comment: I've added the `get_terms()` example in the edited solution.